# Owl Carousel - Add/Remove items dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I'm integrating the owl carousel into an iPad application.  The carousel can have 1000s of items if the user doesn't filter down which items to display in the carousel.

In order to help with performance and loading issues, I currently have the carousel starting with just 25 items and then as the user navigates through the carousel it will dynamically add another 25 items to the end of the carousel.  It does this whenever the users gets about halfway towards the end of the carousel until there are no more items to add.

The problem that is happening now is that there is still some memory issues when the carousel gets to be about 300 images.  The application will crash.

I was thinking that I needed to remove items from the beginning of the carousel but I'm drawing blanks on how to make that work.  Here are a couple caveats:

- I need to be able to maintain current position in the carousel when items are prepended to the beginning.
- The carousel needs to stay in the same order as the beginning array.
- The user shouldn't be able to notice the change in the carousel, can't affect UX.

My initial thoughts was to try to keep say 50 items in the carousel and then as the user navigates back and forth through the carousel, add/remove items from either end as needed.  I just seem to be having coders-block because I can't see how to begin.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Just use one of it function to lazy load:

http://www.landmarkmlp.com/js-plugin/owl.carousel/demos/lazyLoad.html

Comment: I'm actually using the LazyLoading in the application but there is a chance that this carousel can have up to 12,000 images and it still seems to be bogging down/crashing the application.  This is the reason I'm looking at doing this additional dynamic loading/unloading of the items.

Comment: There is a change ... Did You test it ? Lazy load use ajax and it won't load images before its in view.

Comment: ps. If You need that kind of solution for 12.000 items with load/unload then You need to create Your own plugin.I don't know any carousel plugin that will work in that way. But carousel is not hard to wrote.

Comment: Thanks.  I will grab the latest pull from the repo but I just started this only two weeks ago so I think I should have the most up to date code for the carousel.  
I might have to try my own carousel but I was hoping I wouldn't have to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `remove.owl.carousel` to remove element from the carousel, it doesn't disturbs current flow and user will not feel any change in carousel.
I had done it like

```
$('#owl-carousel').trigger('remove.owl.carousel',0).trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
```

here 0 is the element number, you can use it with each element addition.